# powershell to use default ie browser

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I configure powershell command's to use either chrome or mozilla as default browser? My current default program is using IE as default.

The reason behind is in azure cloud if i'm using internet explorer  I can see content from the website listed is blocked by IE due to security configuration,

[image]

Comment: Can you give some further detail? What is the PowerShell command Add-Account? That's not a standard one. If you need to open up another browser you could always call their EXEs.

Comment: @Adbertram I have edited the powershell command. Can you give me an example for the exes . How I tried is add-Azureaccount chrome.exe but it doesn't work .

Comment: I'm not familiar with Add-AzureAccount.  It would be a good idea for you to get more specific.  What parameters are you using with Add-AzureAccount? More specifically, what outcome are you wanting?  Why do you want an IE window to pop up?